# Strange problem with from_utc_timestamp function and timezones in spark

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, timezone

A have a strange problem converting date read from json file in utc format.
I'm Croatia (timezone Europe/Zagreb).
When I open JSON file with UTC datetime values (example), depending where I open it, I get different results for same code.

Example:

```
df.select("start").
    withColumn("start_zagreb",from_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("start")),"Europe/Zagreb")).
    withColumn("start_frankfurt",from_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("start")),"Europe/Frankfurt")).
    withColumn("start_paris",from_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("start")),"Europe/Paris")).
    withColumn("start_vienna",from_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("start")),"Europe/Vienna")
```

When I run it in jupyter notebook on AWS in Europe (eu-central-1, this is in Frankfurt), I get this (**all correct but Frankfurt**):

```
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|start                   |start_zagreb       |start_frankfurt    |start_paris        |start_vienna       |
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2020-08-02T01:45:00.000Z|2020-08-02 03:45:00|2020-08-02 01:45:00|2020-08-02 03:45:00|2020-08-02 03:45:00|
```

So all times are correct but the one for Frankfurt.

If I run same code on my laptop (timezone is Europe/Zagreb) on local spark, a get these results (**all wrong but Frankfurt**):

```
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|start                   |start_zagreb       |start_frankfurt    |start_paris        |start_vienna       |
+------------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2020-08-02T01:55:00.000Z|2020-08-02 05:55:00|2020-08-02 03:55:00|2020-08-02 05:55:00|2020-08-02 05:55:00|
```

I tried with **from_utc_timestamp(to_timestamp(col("start"))** and with **from_utc_timestamp(col("start"))** and that makes no difference.

Does anybody knows what's this about? It seems that if I try to convert UTC to local time in same zone I'm in, I get wrong results...

Spark version is 2.4.6.